# Pandas DataFrame seems not to have "factorize" method

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I am currently studying the jupyter course of Machine Learning from

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml

in chapter02, the Pandas DataFrame "housing_cat" should be factorized by pandas method "factorize"

```
  housing_cat.factorize()
```

However, python tells me

```
  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'factorize'
```

When I type "housing_cat." and use TAB for method selection I cannot find "factorize", too. Pandas is imported by "import pandas" and type(housing_cat) also tells me it is a pandas dataframe. I use pandas v0.20.3
So what could be the problem here?

Comment: The factorize method works on 1-D types, and DataFrames are 2-D. If you can cast `housing_cat` to a pandas Series, you can use `housing_cat.factorize()`

Comment: The notebook was just fixed, it works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas 0.20.3 definitely has .factorize() but its not attached to a dataframe.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html

(notice the pandas.factorize.html in the url)

Instead, its called with pandas.factorize() or pd.factorize()

Comment: @Rockbar how did you cast the DataFrame to a Series then?

Answer (score 1):

There is two way for this .

`df.apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0])`

or

`df.apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes)`

Why cause your problem : Do following will work

```
from pandas import factorize

housing_cat.factorize()
```

Comment: @Rockbar or you can just call sklearn , there is one `LabelEncoder`, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Comment: Yeah I know. But, the author of the book/jupyter notebooks recently changed from LabelEncoder to factorize

Comment: @Rockbar you do not need always follow it, there are mutiple way to achieve this , that is why we love python , *diversity*

Comment: Yes thats right, but as to get started one runs down the examples in the jupyter notebook, and then you will definetely stumple over the code. And as a curious person, I want to know why it does not work ;-)

Comment: @Rockbar I edit my answer, this time it will be work

Comment: I had tried "from pandas import factorize" already, which does not change problem, because probably "housing_cat" is a df, not a series.

Comment: Base on the book , it is a Serise ..

https://books.google.com/books?id=khpYDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=housing_cat.factorize()&source=bl&ots=kLzAMIDtqY&sig=HCXxEtheaHexPArfsDkVNc3rw0k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVm8PRtf_WAhWLzIMKHXaJD-IQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=housing_cat.factorize()&f=false

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ensure that the housing_cat is a Series type and not a DataFrame before applying housing_cat.factorize().

Comment: Thats reasonable